# USB stick is automatically getting disconnected

Tags: drivers, usb

When i plug in my usb stick it doesn't get mounted. So i check `dmesg`. There i could see that stick is getting connected initially but in a second its getting disconnected.

`dmesg` output:

```
[  734.488450] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  734.505175] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5406
[  734.505182] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  734.505185] usb 3-7: Product: U3 Cruzer Micro
[  734.505188] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[  734.505190] usb 3-7: SerialNumber: 173971115603386C
[  734.505645] usb-storage 3-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  734.505718] scsi7 : usb-storage 3-7:1.0
[  735.053026] usb 3-7: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

`fdisk -l` shows only this:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
```

`lsusb` doesn't list my stick.

What could be the problem ?

On windows 7 it gives the error "Device driver is not properly installed".

Comment: Does it work in another port? Does the same port take another USB stick?

Comment: no it doesn't work in another port too. I tried different PCs but all in vain. and yes the same port takes another USB too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your USB stick is busted!

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news and I hope you've got a back-up of the data it contains, but this is typical behaviour of a USB stick whose control circuit is broken...

**If you have no backup:** It looks like the control circuit is broken as it gets connected/disconnected/connected/disconnected/...  Probably the memory chip itself is still OK, so if you have an identical disk, you [repair the USB stick](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=repair+usb+stick) **;-)** or take it to an electronics shop and have it repaired for you.

**Warning:** Repairing a USB stick will be much more expensive then just throwing it away and buying a new one!  This is only to be attempted if it contains critical data.

It's always good to have [a back-up of everything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)!

Comment: In latest portable HDDs they could be mounted again once they left not connected for few hours(>6h). Observed this in Transcend and Seagate 2TB Expansion.

Comment: @ThilankaDeshan-minion91 HDD recovery is an entirely different animal.  I put hose in the freezer overnight, then back-up a last time...